# pi zero with g_mass_storage configuration

Tags: pi-zero-w

working on a pi zero, i'm playing with the usb gadget mode. especially the g_mass_storage was very complicated to get it works.

following this article: [magpi](https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/articles/pi-zero-w-smart-usb-flash-drive)

i tried to add the usb g_mass_storage on poweron.

## two methods were tried :

### first method : using /etc/modules

created the usb space on the pi :

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/piusb.bin bs=512 count=2280
```

added the following config to enable the usb gadget mode:

in **/boot/config.txt** :

```
dtoverlay=dwc2
```

in **/etc/modules** :

```
dwc2
g_mass_storage file=/piusb.bin stall=0 remove=1 ro=0
```

### second method : using /etc/modules

created the usb space on the pi :

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/piusb.bin bs=512 count=2280
```

added the following config to enable the usb gadget mode:

in **/boot/config.txt** :

```
dtoverlay=dwc2
```

in **/etc/modules** :

```
dwc2
```

in **rc.local** :

```
sleep 5
sudo modprobe g_mass_storage file=/piusb.bin stall=0 remove=1 ro=0

exit 0
```

and i don't understand why the *first method* is not working (  Device Descriptor Request Failed. or equivalent on linux ). but the second is working perfectly.

i guess it is linked to the dwc2 module that need times work properly before activating the others modules.

is this a bug on the new version ( because some comment suggest that the first method is / was working well on older version of raspbian).

can you help me to understand this "strange thing" ?

thank you in advance.

Comment: Please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it.

Comment: yeah , i know that thing , but that the only way to get the mass_storage working, thats that way :/ the g_mass_storage is not patched correctly ?